# sybase dbeaver using commas vs sybase Interactive SQL

Tags: sql, sybase, dbeaver

i have a problem with this select

```
select "set rowcount 0 exec up_gen_vyroci_inner_bal", "'", dateadd( dd, - pocet_dni_pred_vyrocim , a.dat_vyroci ) "',",  a.c_poj_sml,",",0,",'" , a.dat_vyroci,"',",13,",",1,",",0
from d_poj_bal as a
inner join d_poj_bal as b on a.c_poj_sml = b.c_poj_sml
inner join c_balicek_bal as c on b.c_balicek = c.c_balicek
where a.c_poj_sml in ( 6142953209) and a.rezim_ps = 1
      and not exists ( select 1 from d_fronta_bal as f where a.c_poj_sml = f.c_poj_sml and a.c_dodatku = f.c_dodatku and f.c_typ_transakce = 7 )
```

in Interactive SQL i get the result:

set rowcount 0 exec up_gen_vyroci_inner_bal ' 2013-06-06 00:00:00.0     ', 6142953209   , 0           ,' 2013-08-15 00:00:00.0     ', 13          , 1           , 0

which i am able to use later for executing my procedure.

but when i try the same exact select in Dbeaver i get the error
[Dbeaver error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clW0S.png)

I already tried to  rewrite the commas but with no luck
I think the main problem is with IDE and different use of commas in both programs, but  I am not sure of how to repair it to work in both.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: looks like an issue with dbeaver and what it considers a valid column name; in `isql` the query `select ","` will generate a result set with a column name of `<blank>`; I think `plsql` would automatically label the column with a quoted comma (don't quote me on that); in (most tools?) if you run `select ",' as mycomma` then you'll get a result set with the column labeled `mycomma`; in the case of `dbeaver` it appears that if you haven't provided a `as <column_name>` clause then `dbeaver` attempts to use the string as the column name but stuff like `","` is an invalid (dbeaver) column

Comment: unless `dbeaver` has a config setting concerning default column names (when no `as <column_name>` clause is provided), one workaround may be to provide `as ...` clauses, eg, `select "," as comma1, "'," as stuff_a, ",'" as stuff_b, ...`

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot as a workaround, but I didnt find anywhere if dbeaver have some config setting concerning default  column names.

Comment: the only other idea that comes to mind, and perhaps you've already done this, is to contact `dbeaver` support directly to see if they can assist